# URL path structure for a website with several directories

Tags: seo, url, site-structure

I am making a website with several directories that will have a high amount of content.

For now I have separated the URLs into categories so that they’re like this:

> www.example.com/student/
>   www.example.com/student/student-name/
>   www.example.com/student/student-name/biography
>   www.example.com/student/student-name/image-gallery/
>   www.example.com/student/student-name/image-gallery/gallery-name-1
>   www.example.com/student/student-name/image-gallery/gallery-name-2
>   www.example.com/student/student-name/contact
>   www.example.com/teacher/
>   www.example.com/teacher/teacher-name
>   www.example.com/teacher/teacher-name/biography
>   www.example.com/teacher/teacher-name/image-gallery/
>   www.example.com/teacher/teacher-name/image-gallery/gallery-name-1
>   www.example.com/teacher/teacher-name/image-gallery/gallery-name-2

There are many teachers, students, galleries, videos, etc.

There are several more categories that are made in the same way, but before going online I would like to check whether this is the best way.

Comment: That would seem to be a logical structure. What are your doubts? What others have you considered?

Comment: Are these actual directories or permalink slugs in a CMS system?

Comment: Also, are the paths actually `/teacher/teacher-name/biography` or does teacher-name resolve to the actual name e.g. `/teacher/JCL1178/biography`

Comment: w3d - i was thinking they are maybe to long, not SEO friendly ? @JCL1178 not sure what you mean, but each link contains content. Teacher name resolves to actual name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a good URL design.

- The URLs <s>are</s> can be **persistent** (they contain no parts that are likely to change; name changes are rare).
- The URLs are **descriptive** (users can read the URL and they’ll get an idea what the page is about).
- The URLs are [**browsable**](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/53087/17023) (users can remove path segments from right to left, and they’ll get no 404).

It’s also good that they don’t contain any ["unnecessary" parts](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/90003/17633) (like, for example, cryptic IDs for person/gallery names). Which, of course, means that you have to take care of edge cases like duplicate person names (maybe append an integer) or same person’s duplicate gallery names (maybe forbid these).

I assume that users get some kind of list of all teachers/students when visiting `/teacher` resp. `/student`. In this case, I’d probably use the plural forms `/teachers*` and `/students*`:

```
/teachers
/teachers/john-doe
/teachers/john-doe/biography
…
```

But this is only personal taste; singular is fine, too.

---

Note: In your example, you have written:

```
/student/student-name/
/teacher/teacher-name
```

I assume that it’s a mistake and you intend to stick to *one* variant: with our without trailing slash. Personally, I’d prefer the variant without trailing slash, but again, this is personal taste.