# Should one use umlaute in translated URLs?

Tags: url, internationalization

I have found at [When translating a site go with URLs in Chinese or English?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98626/when-translating-a-site-go-with-urls-in-chinese-or-english) that

> The URLs should be in the same language as the content.

If you want a Chinese URL, it's pretty clear that you go with

[image: URL in Chinese]

However, I wonder how is it with European languages. Should you replace umlaute by common standards?

For example, what would be better practice, to translate `example.com/product/oil` in German into

```
example.com/produkt/öl
```

or

```
example.com/produkt/oel
```

Answer (score 1):

Special characters can be used in the URL without any problem. In terms of SEO, check this video of Matt Cutts a few years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4TKJwvTu50.

The problem would not be Google but other search engines or apps that are not prepared to work with that kind of characters. Main searchers and browsers will be ok.